# Get the records from an ID to the last record

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get all the records from this ID to last record inserted.

example: 40 records and I want to display data from id(33) to id(40).

Something like this.

```
Select * from records between 33 and last_id;
```

My current SQL.

```
sql = "SELECT id, B5, B6, datetime FROM child_records ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10";
```

Comment: `Select * from records where id >= 33;`

Comment: *"example: 40 records and I want to display data from id(33) to id(40)."* Simply use  `id between 33 AND 40` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following

This query return all record where id greater than 32

```
Select * from records where id > 32;
```

Answer (score 0):

You make the first `$sql` query to always get the last id in table

```
$last_id = always the last id in the table
```

Then in $row['id'] it is the last id you got from SQL query. You store it in variable then use it in main query

```php
// query to get last id
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `child_records` order by `id` DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$last_id = $row['id']; // now you got the last id in table even if you inserted new columns

// main query
$sql = "SELECT `id`, `B5`, `B6`, `datetime` 
FROM `child_records`
WHERE `id` BETWEEN 33 AND {$last_id} ";
```

Then you know how to complete the query right ? just like the query to get last id

hope that answer your question